# Create and checkout to new branch by one command

Tags: magit

If I need to create new branch and checkout to it I use two commands:

```
1.magit-branch
2.magit-branch-checkout
```

Is it possible by one command to create **AND** checkout to new branch?

Comment: Is pressing `b` `l` too much work for you? Or are you writing a lisp function? Also, it's `checkout`, not `chekcout`.

Answer (score 5):

```
magit-branch-and-checkout
```

From the manual:

> b c
>   (magit-branch-and-checkout)
>   This command creates a new branch like magit-branch, but then also checks it out.